# How can I complete this function that will add the users whole number and the decimal minutes based on time conversion?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm working on a calculator. For this portion, I need to add the whole hours to the decimal minutes, but at the same time convert the decimal minutes into regular time. For example, if the user enters 33.57, I want the "current hours worked" to convert this to "33 hours and 34 minutes".

Of course, I'm also going to need to automate the "remaining hours to work" based on a 40 hour week (or how ever many hours they plan on working that week). In this case, I would need it to show "6 hours and 26 minutes".

I am completely new to javascript and this is my first stab at it but I feel like I don't know where to start. I'd really appreciate some guidance.

This is what I'm working on [Click Here for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUdUV.png)

```
HTML Code:

    <!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <title>40 Hour Workweek Calculator</title>

    </head>


    <body>

      <header>
        <h3>40-Hour Workweek Calculator</h3>
      </header>

      <div class="wrapper">

        <div>
          <h4 class="sections totalHours">How many hours do you plan on working this week?</h4>
          <input type="text" class="userInput" id="hoursWeek" placeholder="ex: 40" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <h4 class="sections fridayHours">On Friday morning, how many hours<br />(in whole numbers) do you currently have?</h4>
          <input type="text" class="userInput" id="fridayMorning" placeholder="ex: 33" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <h4 class="sections remDecimal">Enter remaining decimals:</h4>
          <input type="text" class="userInput" id="remainingDecimals" placeholder="ex: .57" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <h4 class="sections convertedTime">Current hours worked:</h4>
          <output type="text" class="defaultCalc" id="convertToTime">

          </output>
        </div>

        <div>
          <h4 class="sections remainHours">Remaining hours to work:</h4>
          <output type="text" class="defaultCalc" id="remainingHours">
        </div>

        <div>
          <h4 class="sections clockFriday">Enter time you clocked in on Friday:</h4>
          <input type="text" class="userInput" id="enterClockIn" placeholder="ex: 7:22" /><br />
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="amButton">AM</button>
          <button class="pmButton">PM</button>
        </div>

        <div>
          <h4 class="sections lunch">Enter today's lunch break in minutes:</h4>
          <input type="text" class="userInput" id="enterLunch" placeholder="ex: 30" />
        </div>

        <div class="sections calculate">
          <button class="calcButton" id="clickCalc">Calculate my hours</button>
        </div>

        <div>
          <h4 class="sections outFriday">Time to clock out on Friday:</h4>
          <output class="defaultCalc clockOutTime" id="clockOutToday">
        </div>

        <div class="lastButtons">
          <div class="clockOutAMButton">AM</div>
          <div class="clockOutPMButton">PM</div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>


CSS:

/*Base style layouts*/

header, body {
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #edf0f1;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 46px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 46px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #96deda 0%, #50c9c3 40%);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.15);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h4 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.sections {
  margin: 30px 0;
}


/*Gray areas that display javascript calculations*/

.defaultCalc {
  border: 1px solid #C3C8CB;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
  border-radius: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 29px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  line-height: 14.5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


/*Sections that require the user to input a number*/

.userInput::placeholder {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgba(149, 152, 154, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 8px;
}



.userInput {
  border: 1px solid #C3C8CB;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  line-height: 14.5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.sections {
  margin: 30px 0;
}


/*Buttons*/

.amButton, .pmButton {
  border: 1px solid #C3C8CB;
  width: 45px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #95989A;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  line-height: 29px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-right: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.calcButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #50c9c3;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  line-height: 36px;
}

.clockOutTime {
  border: 1px none;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #60B6FF;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.clockOutAMButton, .clockOutPMButton {
  border: 1px solid #C3C8CB;
  width: 45px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #95989A;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

output:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}


.calcButton:active {
  font-size: 1.175em;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
  }
  .wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 520px;
  }
  .totalHours {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .fridayHours {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .remDecimal {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .convertedTime {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .remainHours {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .clockFriday {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .buttons {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 380px;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }

  .amButton, .pmButton {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .lunch {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .outFriday {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .lastButtons {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 380px;
  }
  .outFriday {
    padding-right: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .clockOutAMButton, .clockOutPMButton {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .sections, .clockOutTime, .defaultCalc {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .calcButton {
    width: 520px;
  }

}
```

JS Code:

```
function convertTime () {
  var fridayMorning = parseInt(document.getElementById('fridayMorning').value);
  var remainingDecimals = parseInt(document.getElementById('remainingDecimals').value);

}
```

Comment: Where is "6 hours and 26 minutes" derived from?

Comment: @guest271314 (40 hours) - (33 hours and 34 minutes)

Comment: That is how many hours they need to work on Friday assuming the user entered "40" in the first field (how many hours do you plan on working this week). So if they already worked 33 hours and 34 minutes, they would still need to work 6 hours and 26 minutes to complete their 40 hours.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `33.57` to `3`, `34` or `6.43` to `6`, `26` using `String.prototype.replace()`, `+` operator to convert string to number, division and multiplication

```
60/100 * <decimal, .57, .43>
```

that is `60` divided by `100` multiplied by decimal portion of input number; chain `.toFixed()`, `String.prototype.slice()` with parameter `2`.

```js
const total = 40;

let hrs = 33.57;

const getHours = hr => {

  let h = `${hr}`.replace(/\..+/, "");

  let m = +`${hr}`.replace(/\d+(?=.)/, "");

  return `${h} hours and ${(60/100 * m).toFixed(2).slice(2)} minutes`;

}

let worked = getHours(hrs);

let left = total - hrs;

let toWork = getHours(left);

console.log(`${worked} worked\n${toWork} to work`);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to work with such times if you use minutes in your calculations

so, to convert a "decimal" hours to minutes ...

```
function decimalHoursToMinutes(v) {
    return Math.floor(60 * v);
}
```

Now with 33.57 hours you get 2014 minutes  ... there are 2400 minutes in 40 hours, so there would be 2400 - 2014 == 386 minutes "to make up" ....

converting minutes to hh:mm is simple too ...

```
function minutesToHHMM(v) {
    return parseInt(v/60) + ':' + ('0' + (v % 60)).substr(-2)
}
```

or, if you want `x hours and y minutes` - with no `s` in case of 1 hour or 1 minute

```
function minutesToHHMM(v) {
    var hours = parseInt(v/60);
    var hs = hours == 1 ? '' : 's';
    var minutes = v % 60;
    var ms = minutes == 1 ? '' : 's';
    return hours + ' hour' + hs + ' and ' + minutes + ' minute' + ms;
}
```

So, to get `33 hours and 34 minutes` from `33.57`

```
var s = minutesToHHMM(decimalHoursToMinutes(33.57));
```